# "The intellisense of my visual studio code is not functioning"

Tags: intellisense

I was trying to code some Html this morning and my intellisense was not working I'm a beginner to coding so I really need it as it helps me to auto finish some commands that I don't remember

Answer (score 0):

For HTML files, VS Code has an inbuilt functionality called Emmet abbreviations. To use them, you just type some emmet abbreviated and hit "Enter".

So, if you wanted to create a `section` element, start typing `sec` and a dropdown will appear where you can select a recommendation.

For more complex abbreviations you can use DOT to add classes. For example, to create a section element with class "my-section", type: `section.my-class`, and hit "Enter".

And if emmet abbreviations do not work, go to VS Code settings (either by clicking on the gear icon in bottom left or typing CTRL+Shift+P and typing "Open Settings (JSON)"). Type "intellisense" into the search bar inside settings, and check if everything is fine. Also, type "emmet" into this search bar, and check if emmet settings are fine as well.